# How do I search google from within my game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use google search in my game. I'd like to find out the number of results a specific search query returns.

Currently I am opening a URL with a search query. However the way google works is by loading the page and then streaming in the search results. Unity believes the page has fully loaded and then returns the results too soon.

Below is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SearchWeb: MonoBehaviour {

  // I call this method to start the search from an input field
  public void Search(InputField _inputField) {
    StartCoroutine(GetHtml(_inputField.text.ToString(), ShowResults));
  }

  // This is my callBack that will post results in the console
  public void ShowResults(int _results, string _searchQuery) {
    Debug.Log("searching for " + _searchQuery + " results in " + _results + " results.");
  }

  // This method is responsible for recieving the HTML from a search query
  // 
  IEnumerator GetHtml(string _searchQuery, Action < int, string > _callback) {
    // White space in the a google search will return an error from google
    _searchQuery = _searchQuery.Replace(" ", "+");
    // The URL to send
    string url = "https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=" + _searchQuery.ToString();
    WWW wwwHTML = new WWW(url);
    Debug.Log("Attempting to search " + url);
    yield
    return wwwHTML;
    // Process the returned HTML, get useful information out of it
    int _results = GetResults(wwwHTML.text.ToString());
    // Send it back
    _callback(_results, _searchQuery);
    yield
    return null;
  }

  // This method is incomplete but would eventually return the number of results my search query found
  private int GetResults(string _html) {
    Debug.Log(_html);
    // Here I can tell by looking in the console if the returned html includes the search results
    // At the moment it doesn't

    int _startIndex = 0;
    int _results = 0;

    // looking for this <div id="resultStats"> where the search results are placed
    if (_html.IndexOf("<div id=\"resultStats\">", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0) {
      _startIndex = _html.IndexOf("<div id=\"resultStats\">", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
      // TODO - Finish this stuff
    }
    // TODO - For now I'm just debugging to see if I've found where the result stats may be
    _results = _startIndex;
    return _results;
  }
}
```

It currently returns html which doesnt contain any search results

Comment: If its not a snippet, don't post it as a snippet. Just indent it by 4 to get a code block that will suffice. Would'v edited myself but edit queue is full -_-

Comment: apologies. I have now updated my post

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Removed the tag and fixed a grammatical error you missed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think google like you using their services in this way - they'd really like you to sign up and access these kind of things via their [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).  This is a nice JSON based api, so you avoid having to do any HTML processing.  Getting the answers out of the JSON response in Unity should then be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Original tutorials [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/google-search-in-c-a-step-by-step-walk-through-tutorial/#more-3543). Just use **GoogleSearch.Search()** function. Source code project at Github can be found [here](https://github.com/hkusoft/SharpDemos).

```
string query = "The University of Hong Kong";
var results = GoogleSearch.Search(query);
foreach (Result result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", result.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("Link: {0}", result.Link);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```